# Store Costco beans in individual vacuum sealed canisters?

Tags: storage, quality

Is it a good idea to split bulk (2-3 pound bags) Costco coffee beans into separate (1 pound) vacuum sealed canisters? This would be done quickly for reduced oxygen exposure.

I would use up a canister every 2 weeks. Will degradation of the beans over time (6 weeks total) be a significant problem?

Comment: Can't hurt.  Give it a try.  On the last cup open a fresh bag and test if you can taste a difference.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you need to start with the quality of the bean you bought. I have noticed both at Sam's Club and Costco that more often than not, the bags of beans are not sealed.  You need to dig to find a bag where the beans don't slide around inside the bag.  If you can shake the bag and the beans move around like a box of cereal, move on to the next bag!  If a bag has lost the seal, you don't know if it has been 'open' for a week or three months.

Second, the debate goes back and forth about freezing or not freezing. Do what fits your life style best.

Third, the more you can limit exposure to oxygen until you use the bean the better.  Coffee beans are like a lot of other items, they can become stale over time if cared for properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, why not? Imagine a big container with all of your beans, there are gonna last the same time if you separate it on 3 containers. And the "oxygen expossure" will be minimal (not necessary), but at least will be better than having it at one big container.

Answer (score 1):

I store beans two ways, 1. Place bag the beans came in, inside a plastic zip lock freezer bag, squeeze out the air and zip lock freezer bag. Place in freezer, when removing beans, allow to warm to room temperature to avoid moisture collecting on frozen beans after opening. The squeeze air out of original bag, the place inside plastic zip lock freezer bag, squeeze air out of it and refreeze. I do this all the time. 2. Purchase a food vacuum sealer unit and seal-able bags that come with it, add beans to bag, maybe enough for 1-2 weeks of use. Vacuum out the air and seal, place in freezer until ready to use but again, allow beans to reach room temperature before opening bag!

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE! So do you feel that beans really deteriorate slower this way? How long do you think they could sit in the freezer in terms of weeks / reopenings?